# NgxAuthFirebaseUIModule displaying ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Im new to angular and tried to integrate with firestore but getting NullInjectorError R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute] when using firestore authentication. here is my code. thanks in advance.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import{NgxAuthFirebaseUIModule }from 'ngx-auth-firebaseui'; 
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TableComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule, 
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    NgxAuthFirebaseUIModule.forRoot(environment.firebase),   
    AngularFireStorageModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<ngx-auth-firebaseui (onSuccess)="printUser($event)"
(onError)="printError($event)">    
</ngx-auth-firebaseui>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
  printUser(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  printError(event) {
   console.error(event);
  }
}
```

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbZMy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the import `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` as shown in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#the-basic-ngmodule) and the [AngularFire getting-started](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/a26676c69790b9a236dbc08504db705f983bd8fc/site/src/storage/getting-started.md#import-the-ngmodule).